How to Stream Audio from Google Cloud Storage in Chunks and Convert Each Chunk to WAV for Whisper Transcription
I'm working on a project where I need to transcribe audio stored in a Google Cloud Storage bucket using OpenAI's Whisper model. The audio is stored in WebM format with Opus encoding, and due to the file size, I'm streaming the audio in 30-second chunks.
To convert each chunk to WAV (16 kHz, mono, 16-bit PCM) compatible with Whisper, I'm using FFmpeg. The first chunk converts successfully, but subsequent chunks fail to convert. I suspect this is because each chunk lacks the WebM container's header, which FFmpeg needs to interpret the Opus codec correctly.
Here’s a simplified version of my approach:
Download Chunk: I download each chunk from GCS as bytes.
Convert with FFmpeg: I pass the bytes to FFmpeg to convert each chunk from WebM/Opus to WAV.
async def handle_transcription_and_notify(
    consultation_service: ConsultationService,
    consultation_processor: ConsultationProcessor,
    consultation: Consultation,
    language: str,
    notes: str,
    clinic_id: str,
    vet_email: str,
    trace_id: str,
    blob_path: str,
    max_retries: int = 3,
    retry_delay: int = 5,
    max_concurrent_tasks: int = 3
):
    """
    Handles the transcription process by streaming the file from GCS, converting to a compatible format, 
    and notifying the client via WebSocket.
    """
    chunk_duration_sec = 30  # 30 seconds per chunk
    logger.info(f"Starting transcription process for consultation {consultation.consultation_id}",
                extra={'trace_id': trace_id})

    # Initialize GCS client
    service_account_key = os.environ.get('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_BACKEND')
    if not service_account_key:
        logger.error("Service account key not found in environment variables", extra={'trace_id': trace_id})
        await send_discord_alert(
            f"Service account key not found for consultation {consultation.consultation_id}.\nTrace ID: {trace_id}"
        )
        return

    try:
        service_account_info = json.loads(service_account_key)
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_info)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error loading service account credentials: {str(e)}", extra={'trace_id': trace_id})
        await send_discord_alert(
            f"Error loading service account credentials for consultation {consultation.consultation_id}.\nError: {str(e)}\nTrace ID: {trace_id}"
        )
        return

    # Initialize GCS client
    service_account_key = os.environ.get('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_BACKEND')
    if not service_account_key:
        logger.error("Service account key not found in environment variables", extra={'trace_id': trace_id})
        await send_discord_alert(
            f"Service account key not found for consultation {consultation.consultation_id}.\nTrace ID: {trace_id}"
        )
        return

    try:
        service_account_info = json.loads(service_account_key)
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_info)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error loading service account credentials: {str(e)}", extra={'trace_id': trace_id})
        await send_discord_alert(
            f"Error loading service account credentials for consultation {consultation.consultation_id}.\nError: {str(e)}\nTrace ID: {trace_id}"
        )
        return

    storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)
    bucket_name = 'vetz_consultations'
    blob = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name).get_blob(blob_path)
    bytes_per_second = 16000 * 2  # 32,000 bytes per second
    chunk_size_bytes = 30 * bytes_per_second
    size = blob.size

    async def stream_blob_in_chunks(blob, chunk_size):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        start = 0
        size = blob.size
        while start < size:
            end = min(start + chunk_size - 1, size - 1)
            try:
                logger.info(f"Requesting chunk from {start} to {end}", extra={'trace_id': trace_id})
                chunk = await loop.run_in_executor(
                    None, lambda: blob.download_as_bytes(start=start, end=end)
                )
                if not chunk:
                    break
                logger.info(f"Yielding chunk from {start} to {end}, size: {len(chunk)} bytes",
                            extra={'trace_id': trace_id})
                yield chunk
                start += chunk_size
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Error downloading chunk from {start} to {end}: {str(e)}", exc_info=True,
                             extra={'trace_id': trace_id})
                raise e

    async def convert_to_wav(chunk_bytes, chunk_idx):
        """
        Convert audio chunk to WAV format compatible with Whisper, ensuring it's 16 kHz, mono, and 16-bit PCM.
        """
        try:
            logger.debug(f"Processing chunk {chunk_idx}: size = {len(chunk_bytes)} bytes")

            detected_format = await detect_audio_format(chunk_bytes)
            logger.info(f"Detected audio format for chunk {chunk_idx}: {detected_format}")
            input_io = io.BytesIO(chunk_bytes)
            output_io = io.BytesIO()

            # ffmpeg command to convert webm/opus to WAV with 16 kHz, mono, and 16-bit PCM

            # ffmpeg command with debug information
            ffmpeg_command = [
                "ffmpeg",
                "-loglevel", "debug",
                "-f", "s16le",            # Treat input as raw PCM data
                "-ar", "48000",           # Set input sample rate
                "-ac", "1",               # Set input to mono
                "-i", "pipe:0",
                "-ar", "16000",           # Set output sample rate to 16 kHz
                "-ac", "1",               # Ensure mono output
                "-sample_fmt", "s16",     # Set output format to 16-bit PCM
                "-f", "wav",              # Output as WAV format
                "pipe:1"
            ]

            process = subprocess.Popen(
                ffmpeg_command,
                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE
            )

            stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input=input_io.read())

            if process.returncode == 0:
                logger.info(f"FFmpeg conversion completed successfully for chunk {chunk_idx}")
                output_io.write(stdout)
                output_io.seek(0)

                # Save the WAV file locally for listening
                output_dir = "converted_chunks"
                os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
                file_path = os.path.join(output_dir, f"chunk_{chunk_idx}.wav")

                with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
                    f.write(stdout)
                logger.info(f"Chunk {chunk_idx} saved to {file_path}")

                return output_io
            else:
                logger.error(f"FFmpeg failed for chunk {chunk_idx} with return code {process.returncode}")
                logger.error(f"Chunk {chunk_idx} - FFmpeg stderr: {stderr.decode()}")
                return None

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Unexpected error in FFmpeg conversion for chunk {chunk_idx}: {str(e)}")
            return None

    async def transcribe_chunk(idx, chunk_bytes):
        for attempt in range(1, max_retries + 1):
            try:
                logger.info(f"Transcribing chunk {idx + 1} (attempt {attempt}).", extra={'trace_id': trace_id})

                # Convert to WAV format
                wav_io = await convert_to_wav(chunk_bytes, idx)
                if not wav_io:
                    logger.error(f"Failed to convert chunk {idx + 1} to WAV format.")
                    return ""

                wav_io.name = "chunk.wav"
                chunk_transcription = await consultation_processor.transcribe_audio_whisper(wav_io)
                logger.info(f"Chunk {idx + 1} transcribed successfully.", extra={'trace_id': trace_id})
                return chunk_transcription
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Error transcribing chunk {idx + 1} (attempt {attempt}): {str(e)}", exc_info=True,
                             extra={'trace_id': trace_id})
                if attempt < max_retries:
                    await asyncio.sleep(retry_delay)
                else:
                    await send_discord_alert(
                        f"Max retries reached for chunk {idx + 1} in consultation {consultation.consultation_id}.\nError: {str(e)}\nTrace ID: {trace_id}"
                    )
                    return ""  # Return empty string for failed chunk

    await notification_manager.send_personal_message(
        f"Consultation {consultation.consultation_id} is being transcribed.", vet_email
    )

    try:
        idx = 0
        full_transcription = []
        async for chunk in stream_blob_in_chunks(blob, chunk_size_bytes):
            transcription = await transcribe_chunk(idx, chunk)
            if transcription:
                full_transcription.append(transcription)
            idx += 1

        combined_transcription = " ".join(full_transcription)
        consultation.full_transcript = (consultation.full_transcript or "") + " " + combined_transcription
        consultation_service.save_consultation(clinic_id, vet_email, consultation)
        logger.info(f"Transcription saved for consultation {consultation.consultation_id}.",
                    extra={'trace_id': trace_id})

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error during transcription process: {str(e)}", exc_info=True, extra={'trace_id': trace_id})
        await send_discord_alert(
            f"Error during transcription process for consultation {consultation.consultation_id}.\nError: {str(e)}\nTrace ID: {trace_id}"
        )
        return

    await notification_manager.send_personal_message(
        f"Consultation {consultation.consultation_id} has been transcribed.", vet_email
    )

    try:
        template_service = TemplateService()
        medical_record_template = template_service.get_template_by_name(
            consultation.medical_record_template_id).sections

        sections = await consultation_processor.extract_structured_sections(
            transcription=consultation.full_transcript,
            notes=notes,
            language=language,
            template=medical_record_template,
        )
        consultation.sections = sections
        consultation_service.save_consultation(clinic_id, vet_email, consultation)
        logger.info(f"Sections processed for consultation {consultation.consultation_id}.",
                    extra={'trace_id': trace_id})
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error processing sections for consultation {consultation.consultation_id}: {str(e)}",
                     exc_info=True, extra={'trace_id': trace_id})
        await send_discord_alert(
            f"Error processing sections for consultation {consultation.consultation_id}.\nError: {str(e)}\nTrace ID: {trace_id}"
        )
        raise e

    await notification_manager.send_personal_message(
        f"Consultation {consultation.consultation_id} is fully processed.", vet_email
    )
    logger.info(f"Successfully processed consultation {consultation.consultation_id}.",
                extra={'trace_id': trace_id})



Firstly, I don't see why you'd do this in chunks.  It doesn't make sense from a technical perspective, nor a practical one.  Surely there would be times in the audio where words and phrases you want to transcribe overlap the arbitrary 30-second boundary?
I think it would be far better for you to do this as a stream.
Some high-level steps:

Sign a URL for your GCS object.
Pass that URL to FFmpeg (ffmpeg -i <url> ...) and let it use its own HTTP client to fetch and stream it.  FFmpeg will put backpressure on the stream as necessary, and will throttle it as it passes through if required.  (It probably wouldn't be required though, we're just decoding Opus, which takes practically zero CPU these days.)
Pipe the output of FFmpeg to the input of the transcription service.

